# How to map clients' domains to my dynamic server IP address?

Tags: networking, dns, nameserver

I have a site builder (like wix) and I want to allow customers to easily map their domains to my server.

My server IP may change so I cannot suggest users create A record.

I want something like ns1.mysitebuilder.com ns1.mysitebuilder.com without creating my own DNS server that automatically maps their domains to my IP.

How can I do it? Can I use Cloudflare for it?

Comment: If you are running a business you should pay for a static IP.

Comment: This is not the case as we may transfer from one cloud to another.

Answer (score 1):

Without mails (MX records) involved? Very simple: Everyone else should be using CNAME records. They point at your domain name(s) where you can just update your A/AAAA records as required.

However, CNAME records are not hidden, if that is (also) what you want.

If mails are to be received, MX records must still be properly set up. MX records must not point at CNAME records.

Comment: Thanks, this should work but breaks RFCs. The problem is that some providers do not allow users to add CNAME for root.

Comment: Well yes, for root domains it's impossible. There's no other way though except managing the domains on your nameservers.